# Magento Add To Cart returns to empty cart

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Add to cart button returns false from following code:

```
Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action.php::_validateFormKey()
$form_key and Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey()
```

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to test it on default Magento theme.
If it works the problem is with the theme, probably the form key is missing on your theme.

Regards

Comment: It is working on default theme. It also working on all category and view pages. Its not working on home page.

Comment: Compare your code with the default theme, you're missing a formkey somewhere.

Comment: Did you tried to disable all non native extensions?

Comment: I did not disable all the native extension. I have disable html block cache from admin and it starts working. Can you let me why do this issue comes??